# Splitting firebird database files

Tags: firebird, firebird2.1

I have a firebird database that is edging the 4GB filesystem limit size.
How do I split a single database file into multiple files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firebird databases can span upto several terabytes for a single file database. A limit of 4GB is mentioned in the InterBase 6.0 manual, but that limit only applies to filesystems which do not support larger files. As far as I know almost all filesystems support larger files than that (a notable exception is of course FAT(32)). See also [Firebird Database Limits](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-technical-specifications/).

If you do need to split your files, you need to add secondary files. There are two ways to go about this:

1) Use `ALTER DATABASE` to add additional files:

```
ALTER DATABASE ADD FILE '<path-to-file>' LENGTH <number> PAGES 
   STARTING AT PAGE <number>
```

Be aware that specifying a `STARTING AT PAGE` number which has already been created will simply create the file when the next page is allocated. So it will not start at the specified page, but it will start at `<current page count>` + 1. See also page 22 in the *InterBase 6.0 Language Reference* (available from http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/reference-manuals/ ) or page 238 - 240 of *The Firebird Book* by Helen Borrie.

2) (if you need to split an existing database): backup the database and restore it while specifying multiple files and the size of each file:

```
gbak -C <backupfile> <file1> <maxsize of file1> 
    <file2> <maxsize of file2> .... <fileN>
```

For the last file you don't specify a size, it will grow until it hits a filesystem limit (if any), in that case you will need to add additional secondary files as described above. See also page 162 of the *Interbase 6.0 Operations Guide* (also available from http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/reference-manuals/ ) or page 825 - 827 of *The Firebird Book*.

But as I said: on almost any (modern) filesystem the 4 GB limit does not apply.

Comment: Mark, you are not entirely correct. Filesystem is only one of the aspects.

Indeed Interbase 6 and prior use 32-bt file I/O API - afterall Groton DBS was conceived in old times when computers were large, but memory scarce and 4GB looked as reachable as horizon. So it was a real common gotcha in IB5/6 timeframe when HDDs became large, that database grew to 4GB - then Interbase had in32 overflow and started allocating new pages at the db file header destroying the database. This bug though was one of the top priority and was fixed in FB 1.5 or maybe even in FB 1.0

Comment: @Arioch'The I don't think historical accuracy is important here, my answer is more oriented to how it works now.

Comment: i think this historical accuracy is what gave that "common wisdom" birth so should be mentioned even if just in passing. Also StackOverflow can be used by many users including those maintaining legacy systems with FB 1.0 or even 0.9 - so while that issue is definitely not haunting the stated FB 2.1 version, but mentioning it still is important. That si what I did then :-)